# A final variable points to an instance. Can the instance become null?

Tags: java

A final variable points to an instance. I wanted to see what would happen if I changed the reference of the object to null. I am very surprised that there is no exception nor  "is null" printed out. It is as if the line of code `a = null;` has been ignored.

**output:**

> myFoo.name? haha

```
public class TryJava {
    class InnerFoo {
        public InnerFoo(String name) {
            super();
            this.myName = name;
        }
        String myName;      
        boolean isStarted;
    }
    InnerFoo a = new InnerFoo("haha");
    final InnerFoo myFoo = a;
    void bar() {
        a = null; // IGNORED???
        System.out.println("myFoo.name? " + (myFoo != null ? myFoo.myName : " is null "));
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TryJava tj = new TryJava();
        tj.bar();
    }

}
```

Comment: You didn't change what myFoo is referencing, you only changed what a is referring to. Since you don't refer to a after that then there is no effect.

Comment: This is nothing to do with final.  `Object a = new Object(); Object b = a; a = null; System.out.println(b == null);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no exception because final variable myFoo is still references to InnerFoo("haha") even thought refrence a is point to null.For example:at first variable a is refrencing to InnerFoo("haha').Then variable myFoo is refrence to same Instance InnerFoo('haha') by using refrence 'a'.When refrence 'a' assign null;myFoo is still refrencence to the InnerFoo('haha').please study about how object refrence work.

Answer (score 3):

You changed what `a` refers to, sure. But `myFoo` still refers to an instance.